# How to upload audio related to a document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am posting a document with title and details. An audio is recorded as well.

Speech to text recognizes the voice and types out document. Title and Details are saved as a document. I want to save recorded audio as well, so that when i view the document i can play audio as well

How to post that audio?

With document?

or

Create another post/get to store the audio separately?

Comment: Speech to text recognises the voice and types out document. Title and Details are saved as a document. I want to save recorded audio as well, so that when i view the document i can play audio as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply read the bytes of the audio file as a byte stream into a byte array with a file reader. To relate the audio file to the document, let the file point to the unique id/title of that document in the database. Here is an example with a JSON to post for storage:

```
{
   "audioBytes": [5ghcj66g6yf...],
   "documentId": "cchghh-g6y56g..."
}
```

Comment: that's what i thought to do .... create another Modal say Audios and relate the document to it... is this what you asking me to do?

Comment: Yes San. Create a model with those to properties. One prop for the document id and a byte[] prop for the audio file bytes.

Comment: Thanks @EggBender that's what i was thinking to do... But is there any other way?

Comment: @San reading the bytes into a byte array is the simplest and most common way to do it. There is no reason to do it in another way. If you need more properties in the model like the document title or audio file name, simply add them to the JSON too or any additional data you want to store.